# Set Range for axis with google image charts

Tags: charts, google-api, linechart

I am trying to change the range of graph using `chxr`.

My code is

```
<img class="image_graph" width="170px" height="180px" src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=170x180&cht=ls&chco=0000FF&chd=t:<?php echo $test ?>&chxr=x,y,r&chxr=0,0,30|1,0,10|2,1000,0"/>
```

By default it is taking y axis from `0 to 100`.

How can I correct this and to allow changing my range?

I referred [Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/line_charts#axis_range). It says its deprecated. Should I use some other Google library?

Answer (score 0):

[Data Formats | Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats) is what you're looking for.

It seems like *Basic Text Format* only supports ranges 0-100. Try [*Text Format with Automatic Scaling* or *Text Format with Custom Scaling*](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats#text-format-with-automatic-scaling) to define your own ranges.

You can just add `chds=a` to use the automatic scaling.